# Xcode 8 adding .xcdatamodeld file crashes -showBuildSettings

Tags: xcode, core-data, swift3, xcode8

I had a . xcdatamodeld file in my iOS framework which have worked fine with all Xcode 7 versions.

Now if I add it to the targets CompileSources, the `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings` command gets into an infinite loop instead of listing the settings.

I have tried adding new . xcdatamodeld files to the project, none of them worked for me.

This command would be really necessary since my project uses Carthage and the build script relies on that command.

Has somebody experienced the same issue with Xcode8?

Answer (score 0):

`xcodebuild clean -showBuildSettings` will fix it.

as solved here https://github.com/salling/Carthage